# Unable to track (see) Parameters on FB event manager console

Tags: react-native, event-tracking, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk-next, in-app-events

I am using react-native-fbsdk-next for event logging on FB event log manager and passing some parameters
Using this code

```
AppEventsLogger.logEvent(AppEventsLogger.AppEvents.ViewedContent, {event_name: isIOS?"ios Login screen":"android Login screen","event_time": new Date().getMilliseconds(), });
```

event_name and event _time how can I see these parameters on FB console after passing from react native code